Exponential utility with distance to the average carbon emissions of the industry
I am writing a thesis on sustainable finance and I am considering a game where the 2 players are firms wishing to maximize firm value through an investment in green technology to reduce carbon emissions. I have atomistic investors with exponential utility, and I wanted to show that firms are in competition for the green investors' capital. To do this I wanted to make the factor something like :
$$
e^{-\eta q'(\delta - \overline{\delta}) }
$$
Or even
$$
e^{-\eta q'\delta }- e^{-\eta q'\overline{\delta} }
$$
Where q' is a vector of demand for assets (I want to optimize for $q^*$). And $\overline{\delta}$ is just the vector of sample average carbon emissions of the industry. However both have problems, the first induces some complicated distributions due to the fact that in my model the actions of firs are endogenous (They may or may not choose the green investment). And in the second, intuitively I don't like that the average "greenness" of an industry generates dis-utility for the investor.
Could you share your opinion, or perhaps suggest another modification?
Thank you !
